# SQL how to map a row to column?

Tags: sql, mysql

**Database structure** with two 1-n connections.

```
User table
==========
user_id

Attribute table
===============
attribute_id
user_id
attribute_name

Attribute_Value table
=====================
attribute_value_id
attribute_id
attribute_value
```

Is there a way that I can receive the data in the following row style:

```
user_id | firstname | lastname
---------------------------
1       | Simon     | Smith
2       | John      | Doe
```

Where `name` is the first `attribute_name` entry from the Attribute table and `lastname` the second.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do it with a dynamic number of columns is to use dynamic sql- use one sql statement to generate another by string concatenation.

Edit: I am not sure this is possible in mysql since there's not pivot command. Let me know if you want to see an example query from MS Sql I wrote. It is a similar data model, but there's just a lot more fields / joins.

Also I want to point out that you have a flaw in your design if attribute names wind up not being unique.

Comment: MySQL does not support PIVOT syntax.

Comment: yea i know. i just noticed the mysql tag.

Comment: Even with Pivot, you have to know the values, which become columns in the result set. Or you use dynamic SQL, again.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the names of the values that you are looking for, a join will do the trick.

```
select
  u.user_id,
  a1.attribute_value as firstname,
  a2.attribute_value as lastname
from User u
inner join Attribute a1
on u.user_id = a1.user_id
and a1.attribute_name = 'name'
inner join Attribute_Value v1
on a1.attribute_id = v1.attribute_id
inner join Attribute a2
on u.user_id = a2.user_id
and a2.attribute_name = 'lastname'
inner join Attribute_Value v2
on a2.attribute_id = v2.attribute_id
```

or so (did not run this). Use left joins if not everybody has a first or last name.

Comment: >a join will do the trick.

this isn't true, look at the format of the result data

Comment: I dont know the values in attribute_name!

Comment: I thought I read in your question that they are 'name' and 'lastname', but then, maybe I have just been looking at the screen for too long.

Comment: Oh no! It is dawning on me ... in relational databases, there is no such thing as a 'first' and a 'second' entry in a table. You are screwed!